# plotting a graph by calling a function

Tags: matlab, plot

```
M = round(csvread('noob.csv'))

save projectDAT.dat M -ascii
load projectDAT.dat


mat = (projectDAT)
sum_of_rows(mat)
plotthegraph
```

This is my main script. I have a excel file, which opens up a 20 x 20 matrix in matlab. Now I have to call a function in this mainscript, which would find the sum of elements in a row for me and put them in a column vector. Here is my function:

```
function sumRow = sum_of_rows(mat)
[m n] = size(mat);

sumRow = zeros(m,1);
for i = 1:m;
    for j = 1:n;
        sumRow(i) = sumRow(i) + mat(i,j);
    end
end
vec = sumRow;
end
```

I am required to plot a line graph using this column vector. I am supposed to call a function from the mainscript. The function should be able to take the input from this sum_of_rows function. I tried doing this:

```
function plotthegraph(~)

% Application for plotting the height of students
choice = menu('Choose the type of graph', 'Plot the data using a line plot',         'Plot the data using a bar plot');
if choice == 1
   plot_line(sum_of_rows) 
y = sum_of_rows
x = 1:length(y)
plot(x,y)
title('Bar graph')
xlabel('Number of characters')
ylabel('Number of grades')

elseif choice == 2
   plot_bar(sum_of_columns)
end
```

Its not working out though. Can someone please help me out, I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following to get rid of the sum_of_rows function:

```
sumRow = sum(mat,2);
```

The second argument tells the sum to add all the columns in the matrix rowwise, giving you the sum of each row in *mat*.

To plot this vector you need to pass it as input to your function. Also matlab takes care of the x values for you if you do not specify variable along, doing exactly what you did manually while defining *x*. Your function would look like this:

```
function plotthegraph(sum_of_rows)

% Application for plotting the height of students
prompt='Type 1 for line plot, 2 for bar';
choice=input(prompt)
if choice == 1
    plot(sum_of_rows)
    title('Line graph')
    xlabel('Number of characters')
    ylabel('Number of grades')
elseif choice == 2
    bar(sum_of_rows)
end
end
```

So you'd have to call this function passing the sum of rows:

```
plotthegraph(sumRow)
```

Comment: Hey. your code worked jut fine. But when i closed matlab and opened it again to give the code a second try, it keeps on saying: 
??? Undefined function or variable 'sumRow'.

Comment: load project.dat again issue sumRow = sum(mat,2);. When matlab was closed the environment was cleared

Comment: I am running the whole script. its showing everything upto that point. When i first did it, I kept the function sum_of_rows instead of doing sumRow = sum(mat,2), and it worked just fine, gave me the graph and everything. the second time, it just wont do it. Also I have to use a for loop, per the instructions. Any ideas?

Comment: Since you removed sum(mat,2), make sure you put sumRow = sum_of_rows(mat); in your first piece of code, so it works with your for loop! Otherwise when you call plotthegraph(sumRow) it will give you the error you mentioned